# How to add keys and values to Collectors.toMap() by going through the list?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

```
    Map<String,List<MeetupDTO>> employeesMeetups = new HashMap<>(employeesId.size());
    for(String  employeeId : employeesId) {
        List<MeetupDTO> meetups = meetupRepository.
                getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId).
                stream().
                map(meetupMapper::toDTO).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
        employeesMeetups.put(employeeId,meetups);
    return employeesMeetups;
```

I want to change what's on top to the bottom.

```
    return Collectors.toMap(//How do I add keys here?,
            employeesId.
            stream().
            forEach(e->meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(e).
                    stream().
                    map(meetupMapper::toDTO).
                    collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

I don't know how to make the keys match their list, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap()`, this way:

```java
Map<String, List<MeetupDTO>> employeesMeetups = employeesId.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        employeeId -> employeeId, // Key mapper
        employeeId -> meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId).stream()
            .map(meetupMapper::toDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // Value mapper
    ));
```

**Important:** while using the `toMap()` collector, you need to ensure that the keys are unique, or else you might encounter an `IllegalStateException`.

#### Edit

> The key is a unique user id, do I need to look at whether the key is unique in this case? - [Будь как Я](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17286055/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%AF)

> @DiegoBorba you can use employeesId.distinct().stream().collect.. to be safe in case it does have duplicates - [01000001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476492/01000001)

Using unique IDs, `stream()` is enough, but in cases where values can repeat, you can use [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--), as [01000001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476492/01000001) said.

Comment: The key is a unique user id, do I need to look at whether the key is unique in this case?

Comment: I know that the key is the `id`. I just thought that was an important point in case you want to use it somewhere else.

Comment: @DiegoBorba you can use employeesId.distinct().stream().collect.. to be safe in case it does have duplicates

Comment: @01000001 Thanks for the suggestion, I improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple loop?

```java
public static Map<String, List<MeetupDTO>> getEmployeeMetups(
                                                     Set<String> employeeIds) {
    Map<String, List<MeetupDTO>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String employeeId : employeeIds) {
        List<MeetupDTO> dtos =
                   meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId).stream()
                                   .map(meetupMapper::toDTO)
                                   .collect(Collector.toList());

        map.put(employeeId, dtos);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: agreed, much easier to read and debug!

Comment: Код ревьювер решил, что надо в один стрим, ему видимо видней  :)

Comment: But why repeatedly looking up a key that doesn’t change (in the inner loop)? Why not simply use `for(String employeeId: employeeIds) map.put(employeeId, meetupRepository .getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId));` Or, if you want to make sure to have an `ArrayList` rather than whatever collection `getAllByEmployeeId` returns, you can use the copy-constructor, `for(String employeeId: employeeIds) map.put(employeeId, new ArrayList<>( meetupRepository.getAllByEmployeeId(employeeId)));`